# How to use click event on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

How to use click event on  tag without id

Hello everybody, I have a html tag bellow:

```
<a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXX"><div class="fc-content"> <span class="fc-title">event</span></div><div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div></a>
```

this html code was built automatically by jquery so I can't add id or "onlick" event on this tag.

What I want is when I click on this tag, it will open a new windows with href for me. I tried to use

```
$('.fc-day-grid-event).on('click, function() {
...//
});
```

But it's not working.

How should I do for this case? Please help.

Comment: *this html code was built automatically by jquery so I can't add id* — that does not make any sense. How *exactly* is the element created? Post that code.

Answer (score 3):

> this html code was built automatically by jquery so I can't add id or "onlick" event on this tag

If you can't control when that happens, you can still use event delegation to get involved in the click event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fc-day-grid-event', function() {
...//
});
```

That works even if the code runs before the element exists. The code in your question only works if the element exists as of when your code runs. See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As the code is generated after the page rendering, you should use a delegated event handler:

```
$('body').on('click','.fc-day-grid-event', function() {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code is missing apostrophes after the class name and after the 'click'.

This should work:

`> $('.fc-day-grid-event').on('click', function() {
...//
});`

However you might consider to check, if there are other dom elements with that class. An ID is much safer. A workaround could be to use multiple classes in the jQuery selection by selecting the element(s), that matches them all:

```
$('.fc-day-grid-event.fc-h-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.fc-draggable.fc-resizable')
```

but this might still be not sufficient, because these framework-classes seem to be dynamically created and maybe deleted and the selection might be too wide or too narow. You could try to select the a tag with parent/child relations, where you know, that you are getting the right element and you could even use the innerHTML of the elements. Alternatively you could iterate through a JQuery-Selection and check for certain attributes.

I'm not sure, if you want to change the target of the link or the target window of the link. Opening the target of a link in a new window works with standard html by using the target attribute

`<a href='bla' target='_blank'>bla ...`

If you use Javascript for manipulating the target adress of a link outside of the href, the code might get hard to maintain in most contexts and the user might get confused, because he get's to page, he didn't expect. I would try to manipulate the Javascript, that is creating the a tag or if that's really impossible, i would manipulate the existing a tag according to my needs and change the attributes like this, if you want to use jQuery:

For the target address of the link:

```
$('.fc-day-grid-event').attr("href", "www.newhrefvalue.com")
```

Or for opening the link in a new tab:

```
$('.fc-day-grid-event').attr("target", "_blank")
```

Then you don't need to prevent or emit events or create event listeners.

Answer (score -2):

```
<a onclick="doStuff(this)">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: `this html code was built automatically by jquery so I can't add id or "onlick" event on this tag` -> this is the issue what OP is facing and certainly your solution aligns with the issue.